# Nginx proxy /image to /web/image

Tags: nginx

I have an Nginx load balancer in front of couple of servers. I am rewriting URLs to send everything starting with /admin to the admin server, anything starting with /web to the web server, anything starting with /api to the api server.

I would like to now rewrite anything starting with /image to /web/image.

Here is my config so far:

```
upstream api-cluster {
  ip_hash;
  server apiserver1.com;
}

upstream web-cluster {
  ip_hash;
  server webserver1.com;
}

upstream admin-cluster {
  ip_hash;
  server adminserver1.com;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl spdy;
  server_name myloadbalancer.com;
  keepalive_timeout 70;

  ssl                 on;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/foo.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/foo.key;

  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://api-cluster;
  }

  location /web {
    proxy_pass http://web-cluster;
  }

  location /admin {
    proxy_pass http://admin-cluster;
  }

  location / {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

I have an api for image resizing located at webserver1.com/web/image, example URL:

```
webserver1.com/web/image/foo.png?width=300&height=150
```

How to rewrite this:

```
myloadbalancer.com/image/foo.png?width=300&height=150
```

To the web server URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rewrite to transform /image/foo into /web/image/foo and then a proxypass to send it to webserver1.com. Something like :(untested)

```
 location /image {
    rewrite ^/image /web/image break;
    proxy_pass http://web-cluster;
 }
```